Location fetch fails in React Native on iOS 17.5+ using react-native-permissions
In my React Native app, I need to fetch the device's current location multiple times. I’m using react-native-permissions with @react-native-community/geolocation. On iOS versions 17.5 and above, the first location fetch works perfectly, but when I attempt to fetch the location a second time, it doesn’t return the updated location.
I’m using useFocusEffect to trigger the location fetch each time the screen gains focus. Permissions are granted, and the location is returned correctly on the first call. However, subsequent fetches don’t return the current location data.
Here’s the code:
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    setPositionLoading(true);
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        setCurrentPosition({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        });
        setPositionLoading(false);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error fetching location:', error);
      },
      {
        accuracy: {android: 'high', ios: 'bestForNavigation'},
        distanceFilter: 1,
        maximumAge: 10000,
      },
    );
    setPositionLoading(false);

    return () => {};
  }, [setCurrentPosition]),
);

Verifying location permissions with react-native-permissions before each fetch.
Setting maximumAge to 0 to avoid cached data, but it hasn’t helped.
Using the latest version of react-native-permissions (5.0.0) for compatibility.
Has anyone encountered this issue on iOS 17.5+? Is there a workaround to ensure the location is updated with each fetch?
Environment:
React Native version: 0.73.2
react-native-permissions version: 5.0.0 (latest)
iOS version: 17.5+
Any guidance or solution would be greatly appreciated!
